# Use discord.js to get voice channel delay

Tags: discord.js

Since I am making a music robot
But I found that discord’s voice server is often delayed
Cause my music to sound very strange
So there was an idea
I want to detect ping every second
As long as the ping is too high, the server area will be automatically switched

Is it possible to use discord.js to get the connected voice server with a delay of milliseconds?

My english is not good
I am deeply sorry if it caused your reading difficulties
I am studying hard

Comment: Streaming audio with a discord bot has a pretty high latency, but I'm not sure what your problem here is. Is your sound just delayed or does it stutter or something?

Comment: I'm not sure what the English translation of this word should be.
I think it's lag

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to switch a voice channels region if the ping gets over a certain threshold, here's your answer:

```js
const threshold = 200;
let changed = false;
setInterval(function() {
  if (client.ws.ping > threshold && !changed){
    <VoiceChannel>.setRTCRegion(<region>);
    changed = true;
  }
},
5000);
```

Be sure to replace `<VoiceChannel>` with the bots voice channel and `<region>` to the desired region.

Code explanation:

Use `#setInterval` to check every so often what the ping is, if its above a threshold, in this case: 200. If so set the region to whatever region you specified.

It's worth noting this won't exactly prevent lag, just change the channel's region if the ping gets too high.

Comment: The value obtained by ```client.ws.ping``` does not seem to be the ping value of the RTC Region.
This is different from the value given by my discord client.